# Use Unity packaged google vr, installed on the Samsung mobile phone will be reported this warning

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, google-vr

Use Unity packaged google vr, installed on the Samsung mobile phone will be reported this warning, how can I getrid of this warning

remind
  If you do not install the Google VR service, this app may not work properly.Please install the Google VR service from the Play Store and continue

[image]

Comment: Have you tried installing the Google VR service from the Play Store?

Comment: But I do not want to download googleVR service, no service my application can also run normally, I wanted to get rid of this warning

Comment: Seems to me that the warning is justified. If you want VR, you need the VR service.